# document.location.hash not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, postmessage

I'm using $postMessage to communicate cross browser with the parent window. 
Everything works fine in all browsers except Safari. The issue is using document.location.hash 
The hash comes back as empty in Safari.
Anyway around this happening in Safari.

```
function postMessage( msg ){  
  var parent_url = decodeURIComponent( document.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) );
    $.postMessage({ method:'resize', message:msg}, parent_url, parent );
}
```

**Update:**

So the parent window is creating an Iframe which appends '#url to the end of it. I'm using document.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) to grab that url to use as the url for postMessage. When testing all this in Safari V8.0.2 Safari was removing the # and anything after the #. So my parent_url was coming back blank.

The solution to this was to use a &param=url at the end of the url instead of the #. 
I'm not sure why Safari would be removing the # or if it's a well documented issue. I have been searching online to find out more info.

Comment: *Not working* in what way? Throwing errors?

Comment: `window.location.hash`, do not use `document`

Comment: document.location.hash comes back as empty in safari

Comment: So did it make a difference changing it to window?

Comment: window produces the same result in safari.

Comment: Is this happening in Windows or Mac? What version of Safari?

Comment: I just added an update to my original post. I'm on a Mac using Safari 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

If [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash#foo) is not available, why not use [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href)?

```
href    = location.href;
hashIdx = href.lastIndexOf('#');
hash    = href.slice(hashIdx);

// or in one line
hash = location.href.slice(location.href.lastIndexOf('#'))
```

Note that `hash` is not supported in quite a few browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash

Comment: MDN link is to a different API  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location Main issue is most likely trying to use `documetn` instead of `window`

Comment: the # gets removed from the url in Safari.

Comment: Just visited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077188/document-location-hash-not-working-in-safari?answertab=votes#tab-top in Safari and my code returned `"#tab-top"` - that being said, my version of Safari also has a `Location` object with `hash` in it. What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Version 8.0.2 is what I'm using.

Comment: This worked perfect for me in Firefox 51.0.1 and Safari 10.0.3. Great job

Comment: Unfortunately, when using an old Safari which strips off hash fragments at the end of URLs so window.location.hash is empty, location.href also does not contain the hash fragment. Just verified this when having been faced with this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this as well with Safari on an old iPad that I cannot update beyond iOS 12.5.1. I have a small Web app which uses Spotify implicit grant for authorization. Spotify returns the access token in a hash fragment (#access_token...), appended to my redirect URI. This works fine in all browsers except Safari on this old iPad. Safari works fine in newer versions of iOS. So I hooked up Safari on my Mac using its Web Inspector to my iPad and found that both document.location.hash and window.location.hash are empty. So seems like there's no way to get Safari on older iOS versions working with any APIs (like Spotify implicit grant) that use hash fragments when redirecting back.